# Is there any annotation equivalent of "default-lazy-init" attribute in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-context

How can I set this attribute in my JavaConfig application context?

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
    <!-- no beans will be pre-instantiated... -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring [`org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation indicates whether a bean is to be lazily initialized.

You can add it to a `@Configuration` class, a `@Bean` method or a `@Component` (for example `@Service` annotated class)

Example for a single bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   @Lazy
   public Example myLayzBean() {
        return new Example();
   }
  
}
```

Example for all beans in one configuration class

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public Example1 myLayzBean1() {
        return new Example1();
   }

   @Bean
   public Example2 myLayzBean2() {
        return new Example2();
   }
  
}
```

Example for bean found by component scan

```
@Service
@Lazy
public class Example3 {
  
}
```

Comment: I knew that. But if I have like 500 beans, and I what each of them to be lazy initialized, can't i just annotate `MyConfig` class so all beans in this context would be Lazy?

Comment: @toiepp I added more examples, for different configuration scenarios.

Comment: Lol, didn's think about that. Thank you!